# Create wav file from audio bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, wave

I'm debugging a "Speech to Text" project and would like to save, on server side, the audio bytes sent over websockets, in a wav file.

The audio comes from the microphone, recorded by the web browser.
I know those:

- 1 channel
- samples are 16 bits signed integers
- sample rate = 44 100 Hz

On server side, each time I get a new chunk of audio date via websocket, I store it to an array. And when I'm done receiving I do this:

```
full_audio_bytes = b''.join(audio_bytes)  # this is my table of chunks of audio data        
with wave.open("myaudiofile.wav", "wb") as audiofile:
 audiofile.setsampwidth(16)
 audiofile.setnchannels(1)
 audiofile.setframerate(44100)
 audiofile.writeframesraw(full_audio_bytes)  # I tried `writeframes` too
```

I get this error `wave.Error: # channels not specified`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I couldn't find in the amount of logs but there were another error before: `wave.error bad sample width` and that's because the `setsampwidth` method expects bytes and not bits. With `audiofile.setsampwidth(2)`, it is actually able to write my wave file !

Edited code:

```
full_audio_bytes = b''.join(audio_bytes)  # this is my table of chunks of audio data        
with wave.open("myaudiofile.wav", "wb") as audiofile:
 audiofile.setsampwidth(é)
 audiofile.setnchannels(1)
 audiofile.setframerate(44100)
 audiofile.writeframes(full_audio_bytes)
```